# R - order means matrix by column name

Tags: r, sorting

I have a means matrix in R and want to order the columns so to plot them in a particular order. The problem I have is that one of the columns does not get order the way I want.
This is the matrix before ordering:

```
       DMSO     INH    INHLPA       LPA   Y27362 Y27363LPA
2 0.2220375 0.44090 0.4572625 0.4551429 0.262525 0.1912250
3 0.6852125 0.46985 0.4550250 0.4305714 0.246875 0.3527375
```

The command to order this matrix is:

```
medias.prop  <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(medias.prop)[, order(c("DMSO", "LPA", "Y27362", "Y27363LPA", "INH", "INHLPA"))])
```

And the matrix I get is:

```
       DMSO   Y27362 Y27363LPA     INH    INHLPA       LPA
2 0.2220375 0.262525 0.1912250 0.44090 0.4572625 0.4551429
3 0.6852125 0.246875 0.3527375 0.46985 0.4550250 0.4305714
```

Notice that the "LPA" column is in the last place and I want it to be in the second place.
I don't know how to get this ordered the way I want.
Any suggestion?

Thanks, jose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (uses a data.frame rather than a matrix, but should work the same):

```
medias.prop <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"      DMSO     INH    INHLPA       LPA   Y27362 Y27363LPA
2 0.2220375 0.44090 0.4572625 0.4551429 0.262525 0.1912250
3 0.6852125 0.46985 0.4550250 0.4305714 0.246875 0.3527375")

medias.prop[,c("DMSO", "LPA", "Y27362", "Y27363LPA", "INH", "INHLPA")]
```

Result:

```
> medias.prop[,c("DMSO", "LPA", "Y27362", "Y27363LPA", "INH", "INHLPA")]
       DMSO       LPA   Y27362 Y27363LPA     INH    INHLPA
2 0.2220375 0.4551429 0.262525 0.1912250 0.44090 0.4572625
3 0.6852125 0.4305714 0.246875 0.3527375 0.46985 0.4550250
```